# How to set permissions/facl for shared (local) directory?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I finally got to reinstalling my NAS/media-center and while at it I'm thinking
about possible ways to improve security. There will be three users regularly using
the NAS and that is me, gf, debian-deluge (dd from here on).

Now, I would like to make it that I can read/write everything. gf/dd can read
everything, but write only into folders/files they created. The thing is I have no
idea how to achieve that. I'm able to make it that each of users can write/read
everything/everywhere. But this is what I would like (ownership in parentheses,
groups are not mandatory and what they should be is probably part of this question):

```
/home/shared (probably me:me)
 |
 + movies (me:me)
 |  + movie1 (me:me)
 |  |  + movie.avi (me:me)
 |  + movie2 (gf:gf)
 |     + movie.avi )(gf:gf)
 + torrents (dd:dd)
    + archlinux.iso (dd:dd)
    + ubuntu.iso (dd:dd)
```

Now, who can do what:

```
1. I can rename/create/read/write/delete everything everywhere

2. gf/dd can create any new folder/file anywhere

    that means she can for example download subtitles even into
    folder she doesn't own

        touch /home/shared/movies/movie1/movie.srt

    or create new folder

        mkdir /home/shared/kittens

3. gf/dd can rename/delete/read/write (into) any folder/file they own

    that means that gf can do (for example)

        mv /home/shared/movies/movie2 /home/shared/movies/movie3
        rm -rf /home/shared/movies/movie3

    but she cannot do none of

        mv /home/shared/movies/movie /home/shared/movies/movie3
        rm /home/shared/movies/movie1/movie.avi
```

The issue I see is that I'm able to give other users read access to folder
via `rwxr-x---` which would allow read access, but not ability to create new
files. How can this be achieved, what am I missing?